# select xml node value by his name tag in php

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML string:

```
<rootNome>
    <nodeDescriptor name="theNodeName">
        <label>Description</label>
        <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
            <value>
                AnotherValue
            </value>
        </resourceProperty>
        <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
            <value>
                MyValue
            </value>
        </resourceProperty>
        ...
    </nodeDescriptor>
</rootNome>
```

I need to get the value *MyValue* with a direct call by a php script.

How i can do this?

Comment: YOu can use xml_parser_create() to have an array http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parser-create.php , if its file u can use simplexml_load_file

Comment: How far have you gone? Did you find the XML extensions in the PHP manual? Did you choose one?

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can get parse the xml document, the value can be extracted with the XPath:

```
/rootNome/nodeDescriptor[@name="theNodeName"]
    /resourceProperty[@name="PROP_VERSION"]/value
```